# Internet, touchpad and laptop screen stopped working after reboot

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, internet, touchpad

I have Ubuntu 20.04.4 installed on a laptop with kernal version 5.13.0-13.
Everything worked fine, until I rebooted my laptop. Now the laptop screen itself stay on the ACER logo while the connected monitor works. Network via dungle, ethernet port or wifi won't work (says No Wi-Fi Adapted Found in settings). And the touchpad also stopped working.

Since I have no internet at all, I'm unable to update drivers. Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Comment: can you try rebooting again?

Comment: Still nothing sadly. I tried rebooting a couple of times, even just shutting it off for a couple of hours and resetting the battery.

Comment: If you interrupt the boot process at the GRUB menu, can you select an earlier kernel version? Do all these things work there? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 thank you! When I select the first kernel version below it, which is 5.13.0-48-generic, everything indeed works fine! Is there a way to fix this for the normal boot?

Comment: Can you please verify the exact kernel version where it does not work? 5.13.0-??? Whatever you find, please run: `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-??? | grep Status` I suspect it is not installed.

Comment: Maybe not enough space or inodes free?

Comment: @chili555 When I run `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-48-generic | grep Status` I get `Status: install ok installed` as result

Comment: @nobody I still have 490+ GB of harddrive space left. When I try `df -i`, my root has an IUse of 5%. My `/snap/*` folders do have 100%. Could that be the problem?

Comment: "Status: install ok installed" Exactly what I'd expect. However, the task was to find out the kernel version above -48 and run the command against that. Above, I said: "Can you please verify the exact kernel version where it does not work?" Is it -50 or -51 or what? You might see what versions are installed in `ls /boot`

Comment: @chili555 I tried it with all the version I saw with the `ls /boot` command, and only `linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-51-generic` gave an error: `dpkg-query: package 'linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-51-generic' is not installed and no information is available. Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files.`. The others gave an `ok` and the 5.8.* version gave an `deinstall ok` status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> dpkg-query: package 'linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-51-generic' is not
> installed

While you are still booted into -48, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-51-generic
```

Reboot. You should be all set.