# dummy audio output, wifi adaptor not found, touchpad unresponsive , USB tethering doesn't work

Tags: networking, 22.04

**I installed some of the updates I was pushing back** and next day my Ubuntu was broken.

These are the commands I have used:

[image: 1]

Should I factory reset and how?

Comment: Can you interrupt the boot process at the GRUB menu and boot into an earlier kernel version and do all these things work properly there? If so, check here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1417219/internet-touchpad-and-laptop-screen-stopped-working-after-reboot/  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 it worked thank you ☺️.